# Magento - tag page goes blank

Tags: magento

I have a problem with magento tag page url like (site.com/tag/product/list/tagId/1). If tag existed then the page goes blank.
I've already checked memory limit, cleared cache, re-indexed pages but still tag page is completely blank

My Magento version is 1.8

Comment: Can you disable the extensions one by one if you have installed any and let us know your response.

Comment: i don't think this is extension problems, i did something else, i had a backup from very long time ago (but with same extension used) i created a new template with that backup and tag page looks fine, i also tried replacing tag folder with that backups one and nothing changed

Comment: Ohh.. I see. did you tried copying default files and revert back ?

Comment: head.php file in page directory had problem, that problem solved, now the page is loading, but products will now be showed, i will check on that issue now

Comment: Sure Man , If you need anything from my side just let me know.

Comment: thank u, it was just a problem with tag.xml, i fixed it and all thing look fine now

Comment: Thanks you can vote up and be spoarty :D

Comment: dont know how to vote

Answer (score 0):

Revert and copy files from default for Tag Feature and try to fix, it will work as default.